# Run-time error '1004' when running from a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problems with VBA in Excel. I have a combo box that selects the variable `fylke` and I'm running this macro when I'm changing the combo box.

```
Sub findData()

Dim fylke As String
Dim finalRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Valg").Range("Q2:AB28").ClearContents

fylke = Sheets("Valg").Range("P32")
finalRow = Sheets("Valg").Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalRow
    If Sheets("Valg").Cells(i, 2) = fylke Then
        Sheets("Valg").Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
        Sheets("Valg").Range("Q100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

When I run the macro while having the sheet "Valg" selected the macro works as expected, but when I run the macro from the sheet where the combo box is I get an error.

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error

The error debugs to this line of code:

```
Sheets("Valg").Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have have to activate the sheet "Valg" first

**Code**

```
Sub findData()

Dim fylke As String
Dim finalRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Valg").Range("Q2:AB28").ClearContents

fylke = Sheets("Valg").Range("P32")
finalRow = Sheets("Valg").Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row



For i = 2 To finalRow
    If Sheets("Valg").Cells(i, 2) = fylke Then
    Sheets("Valg").Activate
        Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13)).Copy
        Range("Q100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I have run the above code with a combo in another sheet and runs with out issue

Comment: You shouldn't use `Activate` when it isn't needed.  The reason including it fixes the issue is simply that `Sheets("Valg").Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13)).Copy` is equivalent to `Sheets("Valg").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3), ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 13)).Copy` and therefore the references to the `Cells` are pointing to the same sheet the `Range` is on if the `ActiveSheet` is "Valg".  But the better way would be to use `Sheets("Valg").Range(Sheets("Valg").Cells(i, 3), Sheets("Valg").Cells(i, 13)).Copy` (or `.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, 13)).Copy`within a `With Sheets("Valg")` block).

Comment: If you are already Activating the sheet, which is really not necessary, then at least at the following 2 lines you can remove the syntax Sheets("Valg"), since you made it the active sheet, and you don't need to add it as a reference

Comment: you have right @Shai Rado, I forgot to delete them, but you have to check your code it doesn't work!! when I tried I take the error Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: I'm sorry  @Shai Rqado its run I have no notice the change you have been done!!

Answer (score 3):

`Sheets("Valg").Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 13)).Copy` is not fully qualified with "Valg" sheet, you need to also qualify `Cells` inside with the `Range` with the sheet.

You should use the `With Sheets("Valg")` statement to make your code shorter and clear.

Also, you should use `Long` instead of `Interger` when looping through rows, and looking for the last row.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub findData()

Dim fylke As String
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Valg")
    .Range("Q2:AB28").ClearContents

    fylke = .Range("P32")
    finalRow = .Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To finalRow
        If .Cells(i, 2) = fylke Then
            .Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, 13)).Copy
            .Range("Q100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K  that's true, that's what happens when you code with your 2 years old daughter over your shoulder

Comment: Anyway, the PO decided to accept the "better" solution with Activate